# How to get facebook advanced permission on graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm literally going crazy with the new permission system of Facebook.
I am developing a mobile game and I have the code working with the standard access and I would like to start the process to obtain the authorization to use live data but it seem the whole system is broken.
First on some end points like user_friends the Request button is greyed out, it says I need to complete a successful request and wait up to 24 hours, I made hundreds for months it's still locked.
Strange thing it says app review rejected, but I don't remember ever trying the app review and there is no history of it.
So I thought I would try asking for the more basic permission where the button is working, like email and public_profile and it says I must fix the Play store link before going LIVE because it is not accessible.
To fix the link I need to publish an open beta, why is this a requirement? I don't want to do it.
Strange thing I still have a draft of permission request and I have the choice of uploading an apk there, why is it not possible anymore?
Please help

Comment: sorry, but i don't really see a specific question that a third party developer could answer?

Comment: I would like to know the workflow from other developer who used Graph API since Facebook support is inexistent.
Are the advanced permission tied to going live? Can you go live with a closed beta?